# Chromium with Windows 7 Frames?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, chromium, html5

I know this has likely been asked before but I've not been able to find any solutions.

Let me explain my "issue"

I have a custom windows 7 visual style which makes all of my explorer windows dark and simple, pic related:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/rExxt]

I love this theme I've created, and I'd like for these darker windows 7 frames to be used as a replacement to the Chromium/Chrome windows.

I think chromium is great, I love using it and I've tried alternatives (Opera, IE) both of these browsers have their own issues

(stuttering & slow in comparison to chromium OR limited to zero customization without sacrificing some modern functionality.)

Opera 12 is the best solution I found and I guess it does exactly what I want boy does it lag... hard.

However, both of those browsers DO extend the basic windows 7 frames.
(the frames that every other explorer application uses, excluding things like Microsoft Office, Photoshop or Visual Studio which use their own custom frames)

I was wondering if there was ANY WAY AT ALL to somehow disable the Chromium/Chrome custom frames in favor of the default Windows 7 frames used by all other applications.

Also, bonus question, is there any way to get H.2XX video (HTML 5) to work with Chromium?

Not a duplicate since the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but your *"bonus question"* should really be an entirely separate post/question.

Comment: yeah I know, just figured two birds with one stone though.

Comment: Was something wrong with my question? why the downvote?

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=chrome+windows+is%3Aq+theme

Comment: you linked me to very outdated articles that don't solve my issues, I tried those things before even making this question.

Change the line in the manifest file, the line doesn't exist, use GTK themes, doesn't exist on Windows 7, only linux.

Maybe my best bet would be actually downdating to an older chromium version and trying again.

HOWEVER there is a program called Clover 3 that I use for windows which is essentially chrome-style tabs for explorer folders, and this is fully customizable with a program like resource hacker.

Comment: I can actually provide an answer if you guys didn't automatically assume this question has an answer, it actually doesn't. so let me provide an answer to my own question please?

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/Q6Cxh)

Comment: Answer the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ***no way*** of actually being able to disable the chrome frames in 2016 using modern chrome/chromium/opera on Windows 7 despite rudely being redirected to outdated articles.

I feel like it *may be possible* on Unix or Linux without serious effort, however, ***not*** on Windows 7. Edge may also be a suitable alternative for speed, customization, and other modern features, however, it's restricted to Windows 8/10 users by Microsoft.

The way I managed to "solve" my issue was to download a very old version of the Chrome client (beta) in which the Windows 7 borders were still active.

Themes and extensions however are unreasonably restricted by google, lieu of this functionality is likely a ploy to convince the user to update.

However, popular extensions such as stylish and adblock WILL still work if you download very old versions from their respective github repos (you're looking for the ones that have manifest.json files) then you can load these unpacked repos using the developer mode of this chrome version -- however, they are incredibly buggy and do require some serious playing about with.

The restriction on sites mostly only affects google owned websites. In my "Solution" the use of Gmail and Youtube isn't possible, however, most other popular services and websites are.

using Resource Hacker (as I usually do for Clover 3, a Chrome-frame based tab-system for windows) I was able to view and edit the assets of the chrome client, essentially this allowed me to hard-code a darker theme for myself, spending a few hours in photoshop:

[image: Screenshot]

To conclude, yes, it is possible to get my desired results, and have a fully dark non-intrusive, fast browser with windows 7 default frames and extensions using this method, however, some websites aren't functional.

Comment: Old versions of Chrome will not only be missing some features and lacking compatibility, they are also **insecure**. Browser is a critical piece of software, please keep it up to date.

Comment: Yes, this is true, could you do me a favor and add my image to inline btw?